# Get commentaries to the book of Romans to follow along with the bible in Logos Web App

Tags: tools-of-biblical-studies

In a way linked to my [other question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/49675/27054), this is also about the Logos Web App.

Around minute 3 of [this video](https://youtu.be/H6bZWVUmCS8), the presenters are able to link a specific version of the bible with associated commentaries and so that's what I want to do as well. Yet, it isn't clear to me how to find commentaries to the book of Romans to then link to.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's different ways you can do that. The most intuitive for me is to follow the next steps

1. Click the library menu icon. This will open the library pane which has a specific search form.
2. In that search form, write the term "Romans". This is the result you'll get

[image: Logos Web App]

3. Clicking in "High Definition Commentary: Romans" it'll open up the following view with commentaries to the book of Romans.

[image: Logos Web App]